# How to count not-empty rows of each column in one datagridview and show numbers of rows in the second datagridview?

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, oledb

I have 2 datagridviews:

1 - Shows data from database.

2 - Has to show number of not-empty rows of each column in the first datagridview.

I tried this code, but it count every row:

```
     var count = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(row => !(row.Cells[0].Value == null || row.Cells[0].Value == DBNull.Value)).Count();
```

The second datagridview has to show distinct not-empty rows.

Please help to solve this problem.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: What is the source of the DGV?  If it is a datatable this is easier using the datatable,.

Comment: It is a datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
            var count = Enumerable.Range(0, dataGridView1.Columns.Count) 
                .Select(x => new { column = x, count = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(row => !(row.Cells[x].Value == null || row.Cells[x].Value == DBNull.Value)).Count() })
                .ToList();
```

Using a datatable

```
            var count1 = Enumerable.Range(0, dt.Columns.Count)
                .Select(x => new { column = x, count = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row[x] != DBNull.Value).Count() })
                .ToList();
```

Creating a datatable with results

```
            var count1 = Enumerable.Range(0, dt.Columns.Count)
                .Select(x => new { column = x, count = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row[x] != DBNull.Value).Count() })
                .ToList();

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("Column Name", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));

            foreach (var count in count1)
            {
                dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { dt.Columns[count.column].ColumnName, count.count }); 
            }
```

Comment: Does this code count every row? If I want to count unique/distinct rows with values?

Comment: Yes it first enumerates through the columns and then the rows.

Comment: Do you know how to show counts in another datagridview?

Comment: I updated code and put results into a datatable which can be the datasource for the 2nd DGV.